# Cannot install loop-aes-utils on debian 8.0

Tags: debian, package-management, encryption, disk-encryption

I need to install the package `loop-aes-utils` on Debian 8.0 to following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto) Ubuntu tutorial.

It is not in Debian official package however.

**Would it be the `aespipe` package or is it another package?**

```
# apt-cache search aes | grep loop
aespipe - AES-encryption tool with loop-AES support
```

---

My `sources.list` file:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list

deb tor+http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
deb tor+http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loop-aes-utils` is obsolete and was [removed in 2012](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=680748). You should use `cryptsetup` instead, as described in the “Encryption with dm_crypt” section at the start of the tutorial you're following.